React FlexLayout border bar with dnd-kit sortable content causes MUI Drawer to switch anchor
This is a pretty specific combo but I can't figure it out. I have a Caplin FlexLayout React Border bar in a react application that uses an MUI Drawer. The drawer is a persistent mini drawer anchored left.
The content of my flex layout border bar is an MUI grid using dnd-kit sortable, so you can drag and drop the grid items to sort them. This all worked fine as a dialog, but now in the border bar tab content, whenever a grid item is dragged, if the drag path goes over the border bar at all the MUI Drawer seems to show up on the Right side, next to the border bar. It just takes up a column of space and shifts everything left. That's in addition to the border bar on the left, which loses it's controls to expand/collapse when this happens.  I'm using MUI 5.x, and guessing its some conflict with flexlayout-react and MUI, but don't know how to fix this. In the screen shot the block right of the border bar and gear icon shouldn't be there, and you can see its the same width as the Drawer on the left side. It also has the mui drawer style when I look at it in dev tools.
Update: I tried a sample component in the border tab that uses @hello-pangea/dnd and it behaves exactly the same as dnd-kit.


Turns out I had changed my MUI AppBar to position "sticky", which for some reason caused the issue described. I changed it back to position "fixed" as the MUI mini drawer example showed and all is well now. I'm not savvy enough with the css to understand why.
